# How to discard a directory in my branch and reset it to the master branch's state?

Tags: git

I have my own development branch, and I've realized that my last commit included a ton of config files that were changed due to installing a node module locally. (I know that config files probably should not be included in a git repo, but that is not my question).

I know that originally I could have avoided this problem by not staging the node_modules folder, but now that I have committed this, how can I discard my branch's changes to node_modules to be like master's again?

Comment: You can reset yourself to the state before you committed the change using `git reset SHA1`. Do you need something more than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checkout master on the folder:

```
git checkout master -- node_modules/
```

That'll mark all files in `node_modules/` as changed. They'll be like they are on the master branch.

If you want to make it seamless you added theses files by error. Commit the change, then use `git rebase -i master` and squash relevant commits togheter.